# assert tags for element with multiple tags

Tags: java, html, eclipse, selenium, tags

As part of my test I need to check what tags and styles are present for a given element. The element is shown on the page as (bold, italic and centered):

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
   <em>
       <strong>TEST</strong>
   </em>
</p>
```

I have some code to get/assert the 'strong' tag:

```
assertEquals ("strong", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='TEST']")).getTagName());
```

if I add another line to assert the em tag, it returns with strong and I don't know how I can get past this

```
assertEquals ("em", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='TEST']/strong")).getTagName();
```

Also, when I try the following to get the style attribute, it cant get past the em and strong tags. (org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[text-align: center;]> but was:<[]>).
This does work on elements that only have text and an alignment in a p tag

```
assertEquals ("text-align: center;", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='TEST']")).getAttribute("style"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findElement will find `<em>TEST<em>` and hence you get [] as result

```
assertEquals ("text-align: center;", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='TEST']")).getAttribute("style"));
```

To get Style attribute operate at `<p>` tag

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p")).getAttribute("style");
```

To verify everything in a single statement: XPath used below gives a element whose P is centered, has an emphasized text with strong tag. If the element is found, you verified your condition.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@style='text-align: center;']/em/strong[text()='TEST']")
```